# Using legacy database with masterdata in django

Tags: django, database, postgresql

I have a database that is used in another project containing let's say info about employees.
I need to use this info in my project: I have a user and I need to set his job title (as a ForeignKey). This job title is stored in the another project's db.

I configured my project to work with multiple dbs and inspected the other db. Then I created a model that has a field `job_title = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='foo')`.

The other db can't be modified at all.

As far as I understand there are two issues:

1. If I can't modify another project's db, then I can't have related_name.
2. Django doesn't support cross-db relations.

**What is the proper way to deal with two dbs?**

P.S.
Django 5
Postgrsql DB

PPS
Found mistake in question: I ment "related_name" not "related_field"

Comment: You can have a `related_field=....` some queries might not be possible cross database, but some like `my_employee.foo.all()` are, since that only requires one database.

Comment: You'd probably need to write the cross-database stuff at least somewhat by hand.

Answer (score 1):

> If I can't modify another project's db, then I can't have related_name.

The [**`related_name=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) itself has *no* impact on the database. It is just used to make querying more *covenient*. For example to fetch the model objects related to a certain `Empolyee` in this case. If you thus use `related_name='foo'`, you can use `my_employee.foo.all()`, and it will make a query to the database where you defined the model with this field. Given that you do no extra filtering, it works, if models are involved stored in a really different database, then problems might start to arise, but this has nothing to do with `related_name=…` itself.

> Django doesn't support cross-db relations.

Well it can work with *relations* as in defining columns without a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint, and thus if it needs models with `job_title_id = 42`, it can still fetch these in the other database. If there are two *phyisically* different databases, as in not a different schema on the same database, it can indeed not make queries that require tables from the two different ones, since that would mean you make JOINs between data provided by different engines. Some queries however might work, since *only one* database is reality involved.

This is probably the most an ORM can do. One could indeed build some tooling in Django itself that would fetch data from one database, and then from the other in this case, and do the JOINing and filtering in Django itself. But likely that would be quite inefficient, and could also blow up the memory usage: a database often does not make the JOIN completely before filtering and returning results, since ome might for example only be interested in the first 25 results, and thus that would result in useless work and could increase database usage enormously. These are a few reasons why picking different *physical* databases is often not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for such profound comment. However this is the architecture and I can't do anything about it.
What I came up with: I will query info from another project's db and just save the primary key to my db. Thus, I am able to get data from the other db and manually join them on my machine.

Comment: @agas0077: well given that the legacy database is not changed by any other script, it might be worth to "move" data from the original database to the new one. Yes, that will take effort, but probably it pays off in the end.

Comment: can't move cause it is an alive db used by other department and it is constantly updated